# Identifying table format in word document using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am reading word document line by line in C# using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

The doc has both paragraphs and tables. I want to check when the table occurs and get the entire contents of the table, else carry on with the line by line processing using doc.Paragraphs().

Any help to identify the table in word doc is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show some code and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read MS Word paragraph and table content line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011759/how-to-read-ms-word-paragraph-and-table-content-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate question. Please take a look here: "[How to read MS Word paragraph and table content line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011759/how-to-read-ms-word-paragraph-and-table-content-line-by-line)". If you are not stuck to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` give [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx) a try and see this question: "[Novacode Determine If Word Style Is A Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139403/novacode-determine-if-word-style-is-a-table)".